# Is it safe to use /dev/disk/by-id/ instead of /dev/sda?

Tags: debian, partition, udev, dd, disk

I am currently using a simple way to back up the drive `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`.

However, before each operation, I have to check `fdisk -l` to see if `sda` and `sdb` have been swapped during boot.

This is quite inconvenient and error prone.

Is using symbolic identifiers from `/dev/disk/by-id/` instead of `sda` and `sdb` **completely safe and bulletproof** so much that it doesn't require `fdisk -l` or `lsblk` checking?

It is clear that if a disk is confused and `if=` is replaced with `of=`, the consequences are catastrophic.

Comment: What do you mean by "completely safe and bulletproof"?

Comment: Even if the device names were not being swapped this looks like a HORRIBLE way to create a backup. You might consider snapRAID. (but, and BTW, this is exactly the problem /dev/disk/by-XXXX is intended to solve)

Comment: dd creates duplicate UUIDs. You cannot reboot with both drives as then they are identical. Which drive is used may depend on UEFI/BIOS and order they are seen. Better to use rsync, not dd
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331348/can-i-use-dd-to-back-up-a-mounted-partition  I suggest new install, so unique UUIDs & rsync of your data, but not system files.  That is just a copy and not really a backup which would preserve old or changed files at least for a time.

Comment: Don't use `dd` like that - it's terribly inefficient. As a direct replacement (and with the duplicate uuid issues mentioned by others), consider `cat /dev/sda >/dev/sdb`

Comment: @muru I mean "there will never be a mistake of devices"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but my workflow just requires using dd to clone the disk

Comment: If your workflow requires you to do something so misguided then you should redesign your workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the files in `/dev/disk/by-id` are actually just links to a device file.

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  1 18:31 ata-Hitachi_HDS723030ALA640_MK0331YHG99T1A -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  1 18:31 ata-Hitachi_HDS723030ALA640_MK0331YHG99T1A-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  1 18:31 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_43NNVJMYS -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  1 18:31 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_43NNVJMYS-part1 -> ../../sda1
```

This is handled by `udev` and meant precisely for the issue you are concerned about--having a more absolute way to reference a physical disk.  Some more documentation [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Persistent_disk_names) on how it works.

Comment: That's what I meant - are the `by-id` paths permanent, unchanging and protect against device confusion.
I found additional confirmation and a broader discussion [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/persistent_block_device_naming)